# Check for pending AJAX call and wait until it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way, raw JavaScript or via a plugin, that will detect if a given function has an AJAX call inside? I've been working with API's recently, and it often occurs to me that some of my codes ran *"a little bit earlier"* than it supposed to because the previous script contains an async AJAX call. For instance:

```
var doSomething = function(by, activity) {
    // Call something from the API of from another developer
    // or a function() from a 3rd party JS library.
    var anonFunction = API.package[by][activity]; // or anonFunction = 3rpPartyJS();

    if(anonFunction === undefined) {
        return "skipped";
    }
    else {
        var response = anonFunction();  

        // The problem is that the code below will execute not knowing whether
        // there are still AJAX call/s pending within the var anonFunction 
        // initialization. If there is indeed an AJAX call (which sometimes there
        // aren't, depends on the <function name> called above), the script below
        // will be executed a little bit earlier than it should be.
        if(response["success"] === true) {
            ... // do something

            return "done";
        }
        else {
            alert("Failed to call function " + by + "." + me);

            return "fail";
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    // This is successful.
    doSomething("me", "aSyncFunction");

    // This returns "fail", even thought the response returns 
    // successful (after some X milliseconds later).
    doSomething("me", "anAsyncFunction");
});
```

I know how to do AJAX promises on JQuery, although it could take me forever to re-code the AJAX call inside those external JS files. Plus configuring those external JS files would be dangerous, I don't even know if there are other pages that use those JS, that may be affected. Dropping the "re-coding" as solution, I'm looking for an alternative function to check if:

1. There is/are AJAX call inside a function (, and subsequently, every other subfunction/s that is/are been called inside that function).
2. And if there is, would make the browser "wait" until the AJAX calls finish, before running the next line.

Currently, I'm using a clumsy solution that utilizes something similar to `sleep()` function, but I know that is not a good solution. I need something like:

```
}
    else {
        var response = anonFunction();  

        while($.activeAJAX().length !== 0) // <<< something like this
            // will do nothing and wait.
        }
```

Comment: Why would you need to recode those external files? Why not make the call to those apis a promise, ie change this `var anonFunction = API.package[by][activity];` to a promise?

Comment: @Craicerjack The truth is `var anonFunction` is actually inside a `for-loop`- I can't set it as promise at that point unless I remove it from the loop, which I can't.

Comment: You can have `Promise` in a loop! What is wrong with that ?

Comment: Sorry, but promises seem like a natural here - to support multiple parallel tasks you'd have to loop collecting promises and then use something of Promise.all() kind.

Comment: You have a  loop with asynchronous calls, this seems like the situation promises were designed for, otherwise youre stalling your loop on each iteration waiting for an async call to return.

Comment: Those AJAX calls may be(?) originally designed as asynchronous calls, but  I need to perform them one after the other is finished (on this page of course). Maybe because they are not originally called inside an iteration, that's why calling them as async is not a problem. But since I actually call them in my web page inside a `for-loop` (that needs to finish all AJAX call before proceeding to the next iteration) I really need that _"wait"_ function check if all pending calls are finished.